# My ESTA expired in 2014. Is it possible to upgrade it or do I have to apply for a new one?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Can you extend your ESTA stay whilst in the U.S and continue your stay there? Or must you look into getting a visa?

Comment: An ESTA is not a visa. If you entered the USA under a visa waiver, you cannot in normal circumstances apply for a visa while you are in the United States.

Comment: so i cannot renew my esta visa there to stay longer??

Comment: Again, it's not a visa, and you can only stay 90 days on a single visit.

Comment: I think nobody can apply for a visa in the US, under any circumstances, and as others have said, an ESTA is not a visa. It's best to explain what you are trying to achieve in non-technical terms (staying longer? for how long? and doing what?) so you can get meaningful advice on your options. Also, what's your citizenship?

Comment: It is not exactly clear from the question whether the OP actually wants to stay for more than 90 days. From the wording, it may simply be that the ESTA expires in between entering the country and leaving the country. If this is the case, the answer should be that the ESTA is only needed for *entering* the country under the visa waiver program, and thus does not need to be renewed while in the US.

Comment: @Relaxed there are some cases in which visa applications are processed in the US.  More pertinent, it is possible for foreigners in the US to change or extend their status without getting a new visa (since the visa is only an entry document).  However, travelers on the visa waiver program may not change or extend their status.

Answer (score 2):

You are staying on a VISA waiver, not ESTA.

ESTA renewal only means updating your record in a database of people pre-checked for a simpler temporary entrance process. It's the person at the immigration counter who permitted you into the country, for 90(?) days, using data they gathered on you after ESTA registration.

Remember that ESTA registration is valid for 2 years. It's the registration for a process, not a permit. It also doesn't guarantee you will be permitted.

For longer says, you usually have to go to a consulate *outside* the U.S. and apply with a bunch of paperwork. So yes, **you will probably have to leave, spend some time on a different *continent*, and re-enter**. A short trip to Canada and back will also make the immigration officier suspicious. The Waiver is for occassional, short visits to the U.S. - it's okay to spend more than 90 days if it's say 10 times 2 weeks, with always a few weeks in the UK inbetween; because then it is convincing that your primary place of living is in the UK. If you have been abusing the VISA Waiver to work there, be also prepared to be rejected. There is a story on a [UK (?) amateur musician being refused to enter and full body searched](http://www.vice.com/read/i-was-given-a-full-body-search-by-american-border-guards), because apparently he had played for tips in a bar somewhere once...

It's best to play strictly by the rules, as it is probably not fun to be questioned for hours, refused, and sent back.

So if you want to come back after your 90 days, you better apply for a *real* VISA, using the regular process at the consulate of your home country.

Comment: A trip to Canada isn't far enough to reset the VWP clock, we've several questions on here already that cover how far you have to go

Answer (score 1):

From the [Visa Waiver Program page](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) in the section on whether you should apply for a visa instead of an ESTA:

> Also, if you intend to extend your stay beyond 90 days or change your
>   status once in the United States (for example, you intend to request
>   change of status to student or temporary worker, etc.), then you need
>   to apply for a visa.

Comment: The page implies that the OP should have done that prior to entering the US but is that an option now?

Comment: Another statement is that you need proof onward travel. The implication it's that it would be within 90 days.

Comment: I'm quite sure there are also provisions for extending the ESTA Permit, but only for emergency purposes (e.g. you're in the hospital, so can't leave the country). There are also various circumstances under which a person in the USA under ESTA can apply for a change of status. I'm not sure if this includes converting to a standard visa, or just for residency, though.

Comment: @Flimzy VWP travelers may not extend or change status.  The only ready they can stay longer than 90 days is in case of an emergency that prevents their departure.

Comment: @phoog: That's not the case according to my immigration attorney when we inquired about changing status during my wife's ESTA stay.

Comment: @Flimzy did you actually change her status?  If so, using what application form and for what reason and under what circumstances?  Immigration attorneys are not always right.  At least, the US government has a web site backing up my comment.  Of course, government web sites are also not always right.

Comment: @phoog: No, we decided not to.  The purpose was to change her status to be a legal resident, because we got married within the US while she was there on the VWP. So like I said in my original comment, I don't know if a change of status applies only to residency changes, or if it can be used to change visa status. I'm guessing at this point it can only be used to change residency status.

Comment: @Flimzy changing from nonimmigrant to immigrant status is actually called "adjustment of status"; the rules and conditions are different. Changing between nonimmigrant statuses is "change of status" and extending stay in the same status is "extension of status."

Comment: You actually can change to U nonimmigrant status while in the US on the VWP, but you really don't want to need to do this. U means victim of a crime, and you need a law enforcement agency to support such a change of status (e.g. they want you to remain in the US as a witness). There's also V status (victim of human trafficking) which you can actually request at a port of entry. Neither of these is likely to apply to most people, though, and certainly not the OP.

Comment: @Flimzy I have since learned that there is an exception to the VWP rule about not adjusting status; the exception applies to immediate family of US citizens. It's therefore not available to the vast majority of VWP travelers.